# OO Design update multiple tables

Tags: c#, oop

I have a User class as following, it has an address property

```
public class User : BaseObject
{
    #region variables

    private AddressVO _address;

    private UserDM _dataManager;

    #endregion

    private UserDM DataManager
    {
        get { return _dataManager ?? (_dataManager = new UserDM(this)); }
    }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public AddressVO Address
    {
        get { return _address ?? (_address = new AddressVO()); }
        set { _address = value; }
    }
}
```

I show all the details along with address on a single screen. The user can change the details and save.

Now my question is should Address and User have their own update methods?

```
public void Update()
{
    user.Update();
    Address.Update(userId);
}
```

or should user.Update() should update the address as part of itself.

The problem I see with the first approach is that we will need two database queries whereas for second one we will only need 1. But the second one seems better OO design, as each object takes care of itself.

Comment: is the table normalized? means can the address and user be separate tables?

Comment: @RameezAhmedSayad, yes the address and user are separate tables.

Comment: Then having separate methods for entities makes sense if i have understood correctly...

Comment: I would personally have two updates. Reason why is I believe every class / entity should be responsible for itself. What I mean is in your instance User would update/insert itself and Address will also be able to Update/Insert itself. I personally don't like it when there is a stored procedure doing this, prefer to do this via code. For example, you could have a lazy loaded property of address and obviously your User class is aware of an address thus call save on it after User has been successfully committed.